# Two System Reserved partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, system-reserved-partition

I have 2 drives, SSD and HDD.

At the SSD:
I have 2 partitions, one with Windows (10 Creators last update), and the other one with System Reserved (500 MB NTFS).
At Diskmagement, this System Reserved appears "Healthy (System, Active, Primary Partition)". On mouse right click, doesn't allow me to delete volume.
On File Explorer this System Reserved remains invisible.
I already understand that I should not mess with this partition.

At the HDD:
I have 2 partitions, one with my backups and personal folders, and the other with System Reserved (100 MB NTFS).
At Diskmagement, this System Reserved appears "Healthy (Active, Primary Partition)". Mouse right click allows me to delete volume.
On File Explorer this System Reserved is visible, and it appears with a letter identification. It is working like any other drive.

Inside I found:

Files: bootmgr (376 kb), bootsec.bak (8 kb).

Folders: RECYCLE.BIN, System Volume Information, Boot. Inside Boot: BCD, BCD.LOG, BCD.LOG1, BCD.LOG2, BOOTSTAT.DAT, memtest.exe

Question: I am not asking about my SSD. I ask just about my HDD (is a removable drive). Is it safe to delete the 100 MB System Reserved partition in my HDD? May I use this 100 MB with other partition at my removable HDD?

Comment: You should not delete this partition.  The partition in question contains your boot configuration data and is required

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. This HDD is removable. Do you have any explanation about the function of this System Reserved partition? Ok, I won't delete. But if possible, I would like to understand what's the function of this partition in a removable drive.

Comment: When you installed Windows, for whatever reason, the installer placed your BCD data on that drive

Comment: I understand, thank you @Ramhound. Is there a way to move BCD data from my HDD to my SDD, and after that delete my HDD System reserved partition? In other words: Is there a way to have 1 System Reserved partition, only in my SSD?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem!

At my HDD, I deleted the volume (partition) "System Reserved" (first I did a complete backup, preparing myself for the worst). Then, restarted my computer... and perfect!... zero problems.

My case was easy because:
1) I knew the "System Reserved" at my SSD... was the main one.
2) By googling the web, I understood that Windows creates others "System Reserved", in every drive, when BitLocker is used. Is not related to the boot, but to BitLocker. So in this case, is totally safe to delete the partition (if BitLocker is not encrypting the drive).

However, I can't recommend my solution as a general solution.

It is important to add, that even in the worst case, let's say somebody deletes all the "System Reserved" partitions... also in this case there is always a solution!:
1) Prepare a Windows Media Creation Tool.
2) Restart computer with it.
3) Open cmd prompt and write:
bootrec /fixmbr => enter
bootrec /fixboot => enter
bootrec /rebuildbcd => enter + y (yes)
... and restart the computer.
That's all!
This simple command... always will rebuild the boot.

Hope this will help.
Regards